# How to map mutiple keys to single value in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
a = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
a.replace({1:10 , 3:10 , 5:10})
```

Instead of repeating it each time , is there any way to combine keys to replace the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list:

```
b = a.replace([1,3,5], 10)
print (b)
0    10
1     2
2    10
3     4
4    10
dtype: int64
```